# How to send files and attributes to controller in ASP.NET MVC and receive a dynamically generated PDF as Binary as response?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing this struggle for some days now and I really can't get my head around this.

I have to call an action that receives two pictures and 3 strings as parameters, this function will generate a pdf using itextsharp, save it in the server and return the binary array as

> return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "mobile.pdf");

I was trying to used ajax to receive the binary file like this:

```js
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/PDF",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        Id : $("#ID").val(),
        String : $("#String").html(),
        Type: type,
        Image: Item,
        Image2: Item2,
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data != null)
        {
          //Something
        }
    },
});
```

As it is, I can see that I have received the binary information through the network tab, but I have no idea of how to display it as a PDF to the user, anything I try on success will end up simply not happening or I receive a internal server error.

The images and parameters I need to pass are generated dynamically in the view

The action on the controller can be roughly summarized as something like this:

```
public ActionResult PDF(string Id, string String, string Type, string Image, string Image2)
{

System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
//Code...

byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "mobile.pdf");
}
```

any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send this request as a form submission, the browser should correctly download the pdf file. This isn't possible with ajax requests. Here is a helper function you could use.

```
function sendFormRequest(url, nameValuePairs) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = 'POST';
    form.action = url;
    for (var v in nameValuePairs) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.name = v;
        input.value = nameValuePairs[v];
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

You could use it like so:

```
sendFormRequest("/Home/PDF", {
    Id : $("#ID").val(),
    String : $("#String").html(),
    Type: type,
    Image: Item,
    Image2: Item2,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Anthony is correct that JavaScript pretty much lacks the ability to save files locally from a browser, mainly for security concerns.

The simplest option is a normal form submit as suggested already. However if you want to keep the upload via ajax for an asynchronous user experience, you can generate and keep the file on the server. You can then return a unique identifier (such as a guid) as the ajax response. The code can then redirect the window to a new controller action which takes the unique id and returns the pre-generated file as a file stream. The browser will then download the file as normal.

Two issues with this would be ensuring security of the files so malicious users couldn't spam file ids until they crack one. And cleaning up of the generated files on the server periodically.